# How do make sure anything longer than a char will cause an error, then make the user retry?

Tags: c#

using the following method, I am trying to ensure that if anything other than entering A,B,C,D, or Q, causes an error message.

If enter is hit (no string or char is entered) It causes an error with the while(string.isNullOrEmpty(userInput));

and with the switch, it makes sure anything other than A,B,C,D, OR Q is entered, it triggers an error, and asks the user to try again. what I am trying to figure out, is how to make this code also trigger an error if anything longer than a 1 char is entered, and not crash unexpectedly. can someone please help me figure this out ?

```
        static char GetMenuChoice(ref double amount, ref int years)
    {
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*** Invalid menu choice");
                Console.Write("Try again: ");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        char userChoice = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(userInput));

        switch (userChoice)
            {
                case 'A':
                    SetYearsAndAmount(ref amount, ref years);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    StraightLineDepreciation(amount, years);
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    SumOfYearsDigitsDepreciation(amount, years);
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    DoubleDecliningBalanceDepreciation(amount, years);
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("*** Invalid menu choice {0}.\nPress enter to try again.",userChoice);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;

            }
            return userChoice;
     }
```

Comment: My guess is when you hit Enter, your userinput isn't null, but some keycode that represents Enter. Then when you try and parse it to a char, is blows up.

Comment: I would suggest to check with `string` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a do-while loop and for something like this. That way you guarantee the user has tried to input at least once.

```
        string userInput;
        char userChar;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your input");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();                

            // Could ensure valid input (Q, B, C, D, A) in the loop conditions if you wanted 
        } while (userInput.Length != 1);

        // Turn the string into an array of characters. Since we already checked the length we know input is at index 0
        char[] userStringToChar = userInput.ToCharArray();

        // Get the first character out of that array
        userChar = char.ToUpper(userStringToChar[0]);

        switch (userChar)
        {
            // insert cases
        }
```

Comment: I liked this way of doing it, thank you so much ! I ended up making my while loop look like this :

    


`while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput) || userInput.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*** Invalid menu choice");
                Console.Write("Try again: ");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            }`

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to use

```
Char.TryParse(String str, out char c);
```

So if it can be parsed, it outputs the parsed valued to 'c'. Wrap it in an if statement as Char.TryParse returns a boolean; If it returns false, throw the error you want.

This is safer than just using Parse()